# How to fix code in statsmodels.formula.api.ols

Tags: python, python-3.x, statsmodels

I'm trying to fit a model in statsmodels.formula.api.ols using the code presented below. Where do I need to fix it?

```py
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

data['target'] = data[selected_cell] # иначе дает ошибку в ols

m1 = smf.ols('target ~ ' + ' + '.join(feature_list), data=data)

fitted = m1.fit(cov_type='HC1')

print(fitted.summary())
```

I'm expecting output of a table with OLS Regression Results.

But I received the following the error log:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-105-661122a7ca21> in <module>()
----> 1 m1 = smf.ols(formula='target ~ ' + ' + '.join(feature_list), data=data)
      2 fitted = m1.fit(cov_type='HC1')
      3 print(fitted.summary())

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py in from_formula(cls, formula, data, subset, drop_cols, *args, **kwargs)
    153 
    154         tmp = handle_formula_data(data, None, formula, depth=eval_env,
--> 155                                   missing=missing)
    156         ((endog, exog), missing_idx, design_info) = tmp
    157 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\formula\formulatools.py in handle_formula_data(Y, X, formula, depth, missing)
     63         if data_util._is_using_pandas(Y, None):
     64             result = dmatrices(formula, Y, depth, return_type='dataframe',
---> 65                                NA_action=na_action)
     66         else:
     67             result = dmatrices(formula, Y, depth, return_type='dataframe',

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\patsy\highlevel.py in dmatrices(formula_like, data, eval_env, NA_action, return_type)
    308     eval_env = EvalEnvironment.capture(eval_env, reference=1)
    309     (lhs, rhs) = _do_highlevel_design(formula_like, data, eval_env,
--> 310                                       NA_action, return_type)
    311     if lhs.shape[1] == 0:
    312         raise PatsyError("model is missing required outcome variables")

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\patsy\highlevel.py in _do_highlevel_design(formula_like, data, eval_env, NA_action, return_type)
    163         return iter([data])
    164     design_infos = _try_incr_builders(formula_like, data_iter_maker, eval_env,
--> 165                                       NA_action)
    166     if design_infos is not None:
    167         return build_design_matrices(design_infos, data,

..............
AssertionError:
```

Comment: The problem may be caused by a range of reasons - names in `feature_list`, python & statsmodels versions, etc. I guess, this very error caused by the line `assert isinstance(eval_env, EvalEnvironment)` in `patsy` package. Not sure if it is anyhow related to the code in the question. The code works on my machine with simple test data.

Comment: It's strange but this code work on Mac OS x without any changes.